# GlobalFree give an error. Debugger does not explain

Tags: c++, winapi

I have following code to load a html string to an embed WebBrowser control. The code give an error with **`GlobalFree`** (I have marked it and near the end). The debugger simply say: `TestProgram.exe has triggered a breakpoint`, with no other explain.

If I comment that error line, my program can run normally and my browser control load my html string successfully. But if I comment it my app surely become memory leaked.

So what is the exact problem here and how can I fix it?

My environment:

OS : Windows 10
IDE: Visual Studio Community 2017
Complier Toolset: v120

**Code:**

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::displayHTMLStr(LPCTSTR htmlSource) {
    HRESULT                   hr;

    IDispatch                 *pDispatch = 0;
    IHTMLDocument2            *pHtmlDoc2 = 0;
    IPersistStreamInit        *pPSI = 0;
    IStream                   *pStream = 0;
    HGLOBAL                   hHTMLContent;

    hr = webBrowser2->get_Document(&pDispatch);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pDispatch) {
        goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }

    hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **)&pHtmlDoc2);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pHtmlDoc2) {
        goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }

    hr = pHtmlDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistStreamInit, (void **)&pPSI);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pPSI) {
        goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }







    // allocate global memory to copy the HTML content to
    hHTMLContent = ::GlobalAlloc(GPTR, (::wcslen(htmlSource) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    if (!hHTMLContent) {
        hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }

    ::wcscpy((TCHAR *)hHTMLContent, htmlSource);

    // create a stream object based on the HTML content
    hr = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hHTMLContent, TRUE, &pStream);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pStream) {
        goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }

    hr = pPSI->InitNew();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        goto displayHTMLStr_clean;
    }

    hr = pPSI->Load(pStream);
    displayHTMLStr_clean:

    if (pStream) {
        pStream->Release();
    }
    if (hHTMLContent) {
        GlobalFree(hHTMLContent);                      // <------ Error here
    }
    if (pPSI) {
        pPSI->Release();
    }
    if (pHtmlDoc2) {
        pHtmlDoc2->Release();
    }
    if (pDispatch) {
        pDispatch->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: What's `GlobalFree`? You probably have some breakpoint there that's getting triggered

Comment: `GlobalFree` free the memory  which `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` has created. An no. I don't set breakpoint at that line or nearby at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980.aspx), passing `TRUE` as the *fDeleteOnRelease* parameter. This transfers ownership of the memory to the `IStream` implementation. On final release, it will free the memory referenced through the *hGlobal* parameter. Calling `GlobalFree` on that handle again, after the `IStream` object has been released, is a double-free bug.

There are two solutions:

1. Pass `FALSE` as the *fDeleteOnRelease* parameter.
2. Remove the call to `GlobalFree`.

As an aside, the handle to the memory passed to [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980.aspx) should be allocated as moveable:

> The handle must be allocated as moveable and nondiscardable.

---

It's also possible to call [SHCreateMemStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx), which - according to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980.aspx) - *"produces better performance"*:

```
IStream* pStream = ::SHCreateMemStream(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(htmlSource),
                                       _tcslen(htmlSource) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```